# AFNetworking - re-trying until API responds correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm using an API which returns a key `"status"` which can either be `"completed"` or `"not completed"`. I have to to keep asking it until it is `"completed"`. I want to be able to keep requesting the response until I get:

```
{
  "status": "completed"
}
```

Is there a way to do this with AFNetworking? Where I can set a maximum number of requests, and a time interval between requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe so. You will need to maintain your own timer to trigger the checks and invalidate the timer once the success status you're waiting for is seen.